# AngularJs: ng-include not working when placed inside a ng-view tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view

I am loading a html page via angular route inside a ng-view.
The page which I am loading contains a ng-include tag, pointing to 
another html file.

I tried all the below syntax =

```
<div ng-include src="'some.jsp'"></div>
<div ng-include="'login.jsp'"></div>
<div ng-include src="include.url"></div>
```

None working. But If I put the same tag outside the ng-view
its working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `ngInclude` get placed by default in the template or are you putting it there with JavaScript?

Answer (score 6):

The url to the file should be relative to your index.html (main html file).
If your structure is like this:

```
index.html
template
    template1.html
    template2.html
```

and in template1 you want to ng-include template2.html,
you should do

```
<div ng-include="'template/template2.html'"></div>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMLWOxZl2wgNs1oPjnhZ?p=preview) is a working example.

Comment: aaron, Wow, you saved my life. I am about to commit suicide because of this. :) Thanks a lot. +1. Should be accepted answer.